# Expander IsExpanded from dynamicresource, if manualy change not working anymore

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, expander, dynamicresource

After lots of searching I came up with this code to expand my expander by code:
I am new to XAML/WPF so it is very well possible I can do this in better ways, but after lots of searching I am happy I got it working(but not yet completly)

XAML:
Added this to the "header"

```
 xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

then added this to Window.Recources

```
 <System:Boolean x:Key="booexapnders">False          
        </System:Boolean>
```

Here is the part of the expander(the expander is made in a datatemplate that is in a Listview)

```
  <ListView x:Name="lsvteamleft" SelectionChanged="lsvleft_SelectionChanged"  GotFocus="lsv_GotFocus" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Expander Header="{Binding}" Margin="0,0,0,2" IsExpanded="{DynamicResource booexapnders}" >
                                    <Expander.HeaderTemplate>
```

I am able to add multiple items to this listview and so there are multiple expanders made. 
In c# I use the code:

```
this.Resources["booexapnders"] = true; // to expand all the expanders
this.Resources["booexapnders"] = false; // to colapse all the expanders
```

Now the problem is, for example. I got 5 items in the listview and I want to see the expanded version of 1, I colapse them all with a button(this works) and manualy expand the one I want(expanded to see more info) in the listview, HOWEVER after I did this the one that I just manualy expanded won t react anymore on the "expand all" or "collapse all" buttons.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should bind `IsExpanded` to a property on your item, then to expand or collapse all you iterate over the collection and change the value on all items, to change one you just do it for that single item, much more control.

Comment: What do you mean "on your item"? On my class ?

Comment: @Maximc: On the type of the items in the collection which is the source for your `ListView`. (Curretly it looks like you might be using a simple collection of strings, you would need to change that to a proper class which has properties for what is displayed in the header and the expaded state)

Comment: I use a class for the binding. but it is so complex to paste all my code, I got multiple listviews, some who don t got expander and I got multiple ObservableCollections ^^(of the classes I made). The items are loaded from a SQLite DB, I don t think it is a good idea to add a new boolean to the class just to get this fixed. Mainly because the list has more then 100 "Persons" and in this listview there can only be 5 items max.

Comment: @Maximc: You would encapsulate your original class in a view-model which own the expanded property, you should of course not put view-related properties into your model classes. You may have heard of this pattern called [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx), now would be the time where it's useful.